# Implement feature branches in TeamCity VCS plugin

Tags: plugins, version-control, teamcity, plasticscm, feature-branch

I'm currently adding support for feature branches in the Plastic SCM VCS Plugin. I think I have everything ready (clearly I'm wrong) but TeamCity detects all new changesets to belong to all branches. This renders the plugin unusable, since a new commit in the default branch would trigger a build in all active branches.

I have a `PlasticVcsSupport` class extending `ServerVcsSupport`. This is the `PlasticVcsSupport.getCollectChangesPolicy()` method:

```
@NotNull
public CollectChangesPolicy getCollectChangesPolicy() {
    return new PlasticCollectChangesPolicy(this, currentSettings, settingsLock);
}
```

This is an overview of the `PlasticCollectChangesPolicy` class:    public class PlasticCollectChangesPolicy implements CollectChangesBetweenRepositories {

```
    @NotNull
    public RepositoryStateData getCurrentState(VcsRoot root) throws VcsException {
        /* ... */
        BranchInfo[] branches = QueryCommands.GetBranches(wi);

        return RepositoryStateData.createVersionState(
                mSettings.getSelectorBranch(), getBranchHeads(branches));
        /* ... */
    }

    @NotNull
    public List<ModificationData> collectChanges(
            @NotNull VcsRoot fromRoot,
            @NotNull RepositoryStateData fromState,
            @NotNull VcsRoot toRoot,
            @NotNull RepositoryStateData toState,
            @NotNull CheckoutRules checkoutRules) throws VcsException {
        return collectChanges(fromRoot, fromState, toState, checkoutRules);
    }

    public List<ModificationData> collectChanges(
            @NotNull VcsRoot vcsRoot,
            @NotNull RepositoryStateData fromState,
            @NotNull RepositoryStateData toState,
            @NotNull CheckoutRules checkoutRules) throws VcsException {
        /* ... */

        for (String branch : fromState.getBranchRevisions().keySet()){
            result.addAll(getDifferencesBetweenVersions(
                    vcsRoot,
                    wkInfo,
                    branch,
                    fromState.getBranchRevisions().get(branch),
                    toState.getBranchRevisions().get(branch)));
        }
        /* ... */

        return result;
    }
}
```

The `getCurrentStatus()` method seems to be working fine since new changes are being properly detected and the from/to states passed to the `collectChanges()` methods make sense. However, it seems I'm missing something to be set to the returned `ModificationData` objects, since TeamCity is unable to find out the branch for each `ModificationData`. I'm setting the proper parent changeset using the `addParentRevision(String)` method, but that achieved nothing. I've checked the git plugin code too, but I can't see what I'm missing :-(

This is how ModificationData are built:

```
List<VcsChange> files = /* fill changeset data */;
ModificationData md = new ModificationData(
    changeset.getDate(),
    files,
    changeset.getComments(),
    changeset.getOwner(),
    vcsRoot, // Unmodified
    changeset.getSpec(),
    changeset.getId());
md.addParentRevision(changeset.getParentSpec());
```

Any kind of help will be really appreciated :-)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you include override:

```
public boolean isDAGBasedVcs() {return true;}
```

Comment: Yes! That was it! I totally overlooked that method :-( Thank you!